# How to get arguments of a list in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.5.1 and I have this list:

```
my_list = [["could", "you", "please"], ["help", "me", "?"]]
```

The list can have more than 2 sublists but the sublist always has 3 elements. The variables in each sublist are unique in the whole list. And I want to search for "me" in the whole list and then get every value in the specific sublist that includes "me" as different values to assign them to something else.
In example it should print:

```
>>>help
>>>me
>>>?
```

I would also like to delete a sublist in this, how are those possible to do? So far I have this:

```
for sublist in my_list:
    if "me" in sublist:
```

Comment: why are you doing `print("help")` instead of, maybe `print(list)` also try not to use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the builtin.

Comment: what sublist you want to delete?

Comment: does it matter? I will need this later but for now I just need to get the values to assign. I 'd like to delete a sublist that contains a specific value

Comment: Thank you for adding some detail after following up on my earlier comment, but it's not enough: if you want to assign the 3 items in the sublist to 3 identifiers (like `var1, var2, var3`), they will be overwritten anytime "me" is found in a sublist. How many times are you expecting "me" in a sublist? Is it okay to overwrite previously assigned values? Do you want to do something on each valid sublist, before checking the next sublist?

Comment: real variables are unique and look like "f4d0b170-2877-4a92-90eb-eb950a57c636" so i dont think there will be any problem with overwriting

Comment: @OliverW. Although I had added my python version as a tag from the beginning

Comment: Your intent is still unclear. It's why your post is getting so many downvotes, I bellieve. Have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Just be specific about the task you're trying to accomplish. What is going to happen to those identifiers now is completely unclear and leaves us guessing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`lambda & filter & in`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290424/search-in-a-list-by-predicate)

```
print filter(lambda x: "me" in x,  my_list)
```

or with `__contains__` method.

```
print filter(lambda x: x.__contains__("me"),  my_list)
```

It returns all nested lists that contains the specific element

So then you can iterate through them and remove them from the outer list

```
for a in list(filter(lambda x: "me" in x,  my_list)):
     my_list.remove(a)
```

Comment: With lambda, you might as well use `in` though: `lambda x: "me" in x`

Comment: @Bahrom Yes, it it fits better. Thanks

Comment: Never update a list in place while iterating over its elements. Try it out on a different sample and you'll see why: `my_list = [["could", "you", "please"], ["help", "me", "?"], ["test", "me"], ["how", "else"], ["is", "me"]]`

Comment: @OliverW. it works, have you tried? I'm iterating though another list with the same elements.

Comment: @Valentin Yes, I have. Result of using the list I proposed is: `[['could', 'you', 'please'], ['test', 'me'], ['how', 'else']]`. Notice that there is still a sublist with "me" in the result list.

Comment: @OliverW. I have `[['could', 'you', 'please'], ['how', 'else']]`

Comment: @Valentin, it seems to depend on your python version. I get your result under CPython 2.7.5, but my version under Python 3.3 and 3.4.

Comment: @OliverW. Yea, looks like. But you still can save the result of filtering in the temporary list and then iterate through it

Comment: @OliverW. Checked this in python 3.*. It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After your update following up on the comment made earlier, it seems you are looking for this:

```
In [1]: my_list = [["could", "you", "please"], ["help", "me", "?"]]

In [2]: for sublist in my_list:
   ...:     if "me" in sublist:
   ...:         var1, var2, var3 = sublist
   ...:         do_something_with(var1, var2, var3)
```

Note that `var1, var2` and `var3` will be rebound to different values anytime `"me"` is found in the sublist. That's why I explicitly add that you'll want to do something with those variables before going on to the next sublist.

Just 2 remarks: in your original `my_list`, one of your strings was missing a closing quote and try not to shadow python's builtins: I have replaced `list in my_list` with `sublist in my_list`.

Comment: I dont want to print them i just wanna get them to assign them to something else. e.g value1 = help

Comment: @StamKaly that was not clear from your original post. To answer your specific question, there are many things to consider. You are looking for unpacking a list and that depends 1. on the amount of elements per sublist, 2. on your Python version (you can collect remaining packed elements in a variable in Python 3). Consider adding more details to your question.