# Is it possible to break from lambda when the expected result is found

Tags: python, loops, lambda

I am Python newbie, and just become very interested in Lambda expression. The problem I have is to find one and only one target element from a list of elements with lambda filter. In theory, when the target element is found there is no sense to continue anymore.

With `for loop` it is pretty simple to `break` the loop, but what about by using `lambda`? is it after all possible to do this? I search from Google, but did not find the expected solution

Comment: Look at the edit if the top answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290424/filter-a-python-list-by-predicate

Answer (score 3):

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter

> Note that `filter(function, iterable)` is equivalent to the **generator**
>   expression `(item for item in iterable if function(item))` if function
>   is not `None` and `(item for item in iterable if item)` if function is
>   `None`.

So in practice your lambda will not be applied to whole list unless you start getting elements from it. So if you Only request one item from this generator you will get your functionality.

@edit:

To request one object you'd call `next(gen)`

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(next(filter(lambda x: x%3==0, lst)))
```

Would output `3` and not process anything past `3` in `lst`

Comment: Plaszkota Thanks for your answer, but I still can not understand what do u mean by "if you Only request one item from this generator you will get your functionality"

Comment: `filter` doesn't apply `f` to each element of the list immediately. Instead, it returns a generator which, when you pass it to `next`, only applies `f` to enough elements to figure out which element to give to `next` to return.

Comment: @chepner that depend if you are in python 3 or not

Comment: Filter produces a generator (at least in python 3) - it only does computation when you try to read values from it. So if you only try to read one value from the generator with `next` it will apply the filter until it finds a valid value and yield it without processing any more. You could, however keep reading more values, e.g. by conveting the filter result to a list, in which case you would process every input value and get a list of everything that matches.

Comment: @Copperfield Which is assumed in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

with just lambdas is no possible, you need either use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) ([`itertools.ifilter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) in python 2) or a conditional generation expression, and call [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on that one to get the first element out of it

For example, let said you want the multiple of 5 in a list

```
>>> test=[1,2,3,6,58,78,50,65,36,79,100]
>>> next( filter(lambda x:x%5==0,test) )
50
>>> next( x for x in test if x%5==0 )
50
>>>
```