# Filter numbers major than a value in an array

Tags: python

how can I choose numbers major than 0.3 in this array?

```
A_list=[0.7, 0.29, 0.4, 0.31, 0.9,0,3, 0,21, 0.34, 0.48, 0.38, 1, 0.1, 0.05, 0.2, 0.6]
```

Thank you

Comment: Since its a hard coded list and a hard coded constraint, you can just do it manually - `B_list = [0.7, 0.4, ...`

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290424/filter-a-python-list-by-predicate answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

Just use a list comprehension:

```
[i for i in A_list if i>0.3]
```

output: `[0.7, 0.4, 0.31, 0.9, 3, 21, 0.34, 0.48, 0.38, 1, 0.6]`

Answer (score 3):

```py
arr = [0.7, 0.29, 0.4, 0.31, 0.9,0,3, 0,21, 0.34, 0.48, 0.38, 1, 0.1, 0.05, 0.2, 0.6]
n = float(input())
arr = list(filter(lambda x: x > n, arr))
print(arr)
```

I think this is a most pythonic way to do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

A one liner answer for a one liner question :-)

```
list(filter((0.3).__ge__,A_list))
```

Comment: if you want to golf-code-it, drop the parentheses around 0.3 ;) `list(filter(0.3.__ge__,A_list))`, that said the list comprehension is still shorter :p